# Add numbers in mixed array

Tags: ruby

My expectation for this code is the number 3. Why doesn't this work?

```
  mixed_array=[1,'cat',2]
  mixed_array.inject(0) do |memo,num|
    memo += num if num.is_a?Integer
  end

 NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there:

```
mixed_array.inject(0) do |memo, num|
  next memo unless num.is_a?(Integer)
  memo + num
end
#=> 3
```

Making your code working:

```
mixed_array.inject(0) do |memo, num|
  memo += num if num.is_a?(Integer)
  memo # return memo on each iteration, because it becomes nil with non-integer element
end
#=> 3
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have doesn't work because:

1. The value of `memo += num if num.is_a?Integer` is `nil` when `num` is not an `Integer`.
2. The value of each block is fed to the next iteration as `memo`.

Your block evaluates to `nil` on the second iteration so you're going to end up trying to evaluate:

```
nil += 2 if 2.is_a? Integer
```

and there's your NoMethodError.

You're probably better off doing this in two steps for clarity:

```
mixed_array.select { |e| e.is_a? Integer }.inject(:+)
```

or maybe even the looser version:

```
mixed_array.select { |e| e.is_a? Numeric }.inject(:+)
```

or with newer versions of Ruby:

```
mixed_array.select { |e| e.is_a? Numeric }.sum
```

If you're not dogmatically opposed to ternaries then you could also say things like:

```
mixed_array.inject(0) { |memo, num| memo + (num.is_a?(Integer) ? num : 0) }
mixed_array.sum { |e| e.is_a?(Integer) ? e : 0 }
```

---

If you know that the non-numeric elements of `mixed_array` are strings that don't look like numbers or start with numbers (i.e. nothing like `'0'`, `'11 pancakes'`, ...) then you could say:

```
mixed_array.map(&:to_i).inject(:+)
mixed_array.inject(0) { |memo, num| memo + num.to_i }
...
```

but that's probably making too many assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this a lot more easily if you consider it as a two stage operation rather than one:

```
mixed_array=[1,'cat',2]

mixed_array.grep(Integer).inject(0, :+)
# => 3
```

This filters out all the non-Integer elements from the array and adds the rest together.

Remember that `inject` takes the return value from the previous iteration as the seed for the next. Your `if` clause *must* return an alternate value. You end up with this if you fix it:

```
memo += num.is_a?(Integer) ? num : 0
```

You could also go with a *good-enough* solution like:

```
memo += num.to_i
```

Depending on what sort of data you're trying to screen out.

Answer (score 0):

```
mixed_array = [1, 'cat', 2, [3, 4], :a, { b: 5, c: 6 }, 7]

mixed_array.reduce(0) { |tot, obj| tot += Integer(obj) rescue 0 }
  #=> 10
```

When the array may include one or more floats and you want to return a float:

```
mixed_array = [1, 'cat', 2, [3, 4], :a, { b: 5, c: 6 }, 7, 8.123]

mixed_array.reduce(0) { |tot, obj| tot += Float(obj) rescue 0 }
  #=> 18.122999999999998
```

See [Kernel::Integer](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer) and [Kernel::Float](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Float).